# Compare and change characters from String in Java using List

Tags: java

I am trying to check if my String `tempName` contains a vowel. If it does, I am trying to make it replace the first vowel it found with a random vowel from my list. However, I am stuck. I have tried a few different things, but none have worked so far. `"vowel here?"` is what I should replace to make this work. I have tried with just doing "a", "e", etc, but that is duplicate code.

```
String newtempName = "";
String tempName = "Charlie819"; //Will always be a random string up to 12 characters. Can also include digits. 

String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"};

if(tempName.contains("[")) {
    log("contains unallowed symbol");
} else {
    log("Original name: " + tempName);

    for (String tempName : vowels) {
        newtempName = tempName.replaceAll("vowel here?", vowels[Calculations.random(5)]);
    }

    log("Final name: " + newtempName );
}
```

Comment: It would help if you showed a before and after example.

Comment: Use [aeiou] in place of "vowel here?", might resolve your issue.

Comment: You have 2 variables named `tempName`. It would be less confusing if they had different names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replaceFirst` which takes a regular expression.

- `[aeiouyAEIOUY]` means find one of these
- `r.nextInt(6)` is from the Random class - you can use your own to give a value from 0 to 5.

```
String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"};
Random r = new Random();
String tempName = "Charlie819"; 
tempName = tempName.replaceFirst("[aeiouyAEIOUY]", vowels[r.nextInt(6)]);
System.out.println(tempName);
```

Prints

```
Chorlie819
```

Note that you are only replacing with the first 6 vowels.  Increase the number to use the upper case ones too if you want.

And finally, it is possible that your resultant name could be the same as you may replace the vowel with the same one (it is random after all). You can prevent that from doing the following (there are more efficient ways but this will suffice for this problem).

```
String tempName = "Charlie819";
String newTempName = tempName;

// continue until the names are different.
while (tempName.equals(newTempName)) {
    newTempName = tempName.replaceFirst("[aeiouAEIOUY]", vowels[r.nextInt(6)]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution, based on regular expressions.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Input temp name
        String tempName = "Charlie819"; //Will always be a random string up to 12 characters. Can also include digits.

        // Our vowel array
        String[] vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"};

        // Regex pattern that matches all vowels
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiouyAEIOUY]");

        // Feeding temp name into patternMatcher
        String output = pattern.matcher(tempName)
                // Replacing first match with a random vowel.
                // Random.nextInt(int bound) returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and the bound (exclusive)
                .replaceFirst(vowels[new Random().nextInt(vowels.length)]);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chirlie819
```